# Construct a superset from pandas groupby operation result

Tags: python, pandas

```
name_region
bahia                    [10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4]
distrito_federal      [9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4]
goias                 [9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4]
maranhao                 [10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4]
mato_grosso           [9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4]
mato_grosso_do_sul    [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3]
```

I have a pandas series above, obtained from a groupby operation. The 2nd column represents months of the year. How do I construct a superset of months i.e. `[8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4]` since that represents all possible months present in 
the dataset

--NOTE:
I do want to preserve order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [itertools recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) `unique_everseen` (which preserves order) like so:

```
>>> [i for i in unique_everseen([z for z in y['months'] for x,y in df.iterrows()])]
[9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Definition of `unique_everseen`:

```
import itertools as it
def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."
    # unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D
    # unique_everseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C D
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    if key is None:
        for element in it.ifilterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
            seen_add(element)
            yield element
    else:
        for element in iterable:
            k = key(element)
            if k not in seen:
                seen_add(k)
                yield element
```

Answer (score 1):

*I seem to have misinterpreted the data structure in the question, but as it might be useful for similar cases, I will keep this answer here for future reference.*

You can use numpy's unique function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1,3,5], "y": [3,4,5]})

print np.unique(df) # prints [1 3 4 5]
```

Comment: thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I should have been clearer in my question.a) It is actually a pandas series and b) np.unique will not preserve order, which I do want to preserve

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a way to do this more cleanly in Pandas so if anyone else knows please answer... Looking at the types this seems like a time for folding over that column.

I didn't see a fold operation in pandas, so maybe just a for loop that accumulates.. i.e.

```
all_months = []
for row in df.iterrows():
    months = row['months']
    all_months += [e for e in months if not e in all_months]
```

on second thought.. would use `set` instead of complicated for comprehension

```
all_months = set()
for row in df.iterrows():
    months = set(row['months'])
    all_months = all_months.union(months)
```

hmm just saw the other guys answer, haven't tested it.. but it looks better! choose that one :). Posting this just in case it helps someone...